# How can I have a inner div wrap internally before wrapping as a whole?

Tags: html, css, web

On my website, I have a div that wraps around two other divs. The left inner div is thin in width, while the right div is rather wide (and consists of text).

When I reduce the width of my window, once I reach the rightmost edge of the rightmost inner div, the entire div (and all its contents) wraps beneath the left inner div. As I further resize my window, the once right div's content (text) begins to wrap.

Essentially, I have this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#leftdiv {
  float: left;
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftdiv">
    shortleft
  </div>
  <div id="rightdiv">
    longrightlongrightlongright
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it is my desire that the text within the right div wrap before the entire div wraps to beneath the left div. What can I do to modify my code to make that happen?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yntBy/?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, I believe that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
 }

#leftdiv {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#rightdiv {
  width: 79%
  float: right;
 }
```

If you want to see this in action, look at my web page at

```
http://sherwoods-forests.com
```

Percents should never add to 100.  You sometimes get oddball results due to rounding when the render engine calculates the number of pixels.

The navigation bar on the left is done exactly this way.
Within the content div each picture along with it's caption is floated either left or right, and the main body text wraps around.  You will also need to play with margins of the embedded divs